# PyTorch Geometric heterogeneous graph, getting error "RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 must have the same dtype"

Tags: graph, pytorch, pytorch-geometric, heterogeneous

I am currently attempting to make a heterogeneous graph regression model, but when I run the code I get the error: "RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 must have the same dtype".

The code can be found below:

```
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch_geometric.transforms as T
from torch_geometric.nn import SAGEConv, to_hetero
from torch_geometric.nn import global_mean_pool
from torch_geometric.nn import Linear, SAGEConv, to_hetero


class GNNHetero(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, hidden_channels):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = SAGEConv((-1, -1), hidden_channels)
        self.conv2 = SAGEConv((-1, -1), 1)

    def forward(self, x, edge_index):
        x = self.conv1(x, edge_index).relu()
        x = self.conv2(x, edge_index)
        print(x.dtype)

        return x
    
data = dataset[0]
model = to_hetero(GNNHetero(64), data.metadata(), aggr='sum')

from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter
writer = SummaryWriter()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)
criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss()

def train_hetero():
    model.train()

    for batch in train_loader:  # Iterate in batches over the training dataset.

        out = model(batch.x_dict, batch.edge_index_dict)  # Perform a single forward pass.
        target = data.y.unsqueeze(1)
        loss = criterion(out, target)  # Compute the loss.
        loss.backward()  # Derive gradients.
        optimizer.step()  # Update parameters based on gradients.
        optimizer.zero_grad()  # Clear gradients.

for epoch in range(1, 171):
    print(f'Epoch: {epoch}')
    train_hetero()

print('Done!')
```

`dataset` is a list of 1000 `HeteroData` objects.

The datatype of x in the forward method is 'Proxy(getattr_1)'.  I would be extremely grateful for any tips.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with how your `train_loader` object has items, `batch.x_dict` is probably an instance of a dictionary. Try printing it's `dtype`. 
Side note - you have imported `SAGEConv` and `to_hetero` twice.